# Dax - dynamic attribute value based on filter parameter

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerpivot, ssas-tabular

I need to create a calculated column that is based on another column but depends on the date filter the report is run for.

If the item is own for more than a year it is 'Comparable' if less than a year it is 'Non Comparable'.
I have `Item`, `DateOfPurchase` in `T1` and `Date` in `T2` (`Period` table)
I have come up with DAX using `today()` but it only works if we report on today's date.

This didn't work (no idea why)

```
=if( dateadd( 'Item'[PurchaseDate],1,year)<today(),"Comp","Non-Comp")
```

This worked but only for current period

```
=DATEDIFF('Item'[PurchaseDate],today(),MONTH) 
= if('Item'[DateDiff]>12,"Comp","NonComp")
```

However, I can not use that column when running report for a different period, because attribute is not valid for prior periods.

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow. Your question isn't very clean. To receive wuality answers, try checking out the guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: As calculated column is statically calculated at loading time, it is not possible to recalculate it on the fly based on the filter condition. Best bet is to prepare different columns for all period scopes, such as "Year Comparable" or "Month Comparable".

Comment: If you provide a clear example with a table and a clear explanation of the expected behaviour in different scenarios, people might be able to help you

Answer (score 0):

Since calculated columns are computed only once, when the table is processed/refreshed, you cannot use a calculated column for your scenario.

Instead, consider using a disconnected [parameter table](https://www.daxpatterns.com/parameter-table/). In your case, this would be a table with 1 column and just 2 rows: "Comp" and "NonComp". You can create this as a calculated table like so:

```
ParameterTable = DATETABLE("Value", STRING, {{"Comp", "NonComp"}})
```

Based on what the user selects on this table - which you can find using `SELECTEDVALUE(ParameterTable[Value])` - you apply the relevant logic in a **measure** instead:

```
BaseMeasure =
// Whatever you are trying to calculate
SUM(Item[Amount])

Measure =
// This measure will respect the user selection (Comp / NonComp) and the current period:
VAR compValue = SELECTEDVALUE(ParameterTable[Value])
VAR today = MAX('Date'[Period])
RETURN
SWITCH(
    compValue,
    "Comp", CALCULATE( [BaseMeasure] , DATEDIFF('Item'[PurchaseDate], today, MONTH) > 12),
    "NonComp", CALCULATE( [BaseMeasure] , DATEDIFF('Item'[PurchaseDate], today, MONTH) < 12),
    [BaseMeasure]  // Fallback, in case user didn't select Comp/NonComp
)
```

If you have multiple base measures in your report, you will need to implement this pattern for each of your base measures.